# Prove existence symmetrical solution of $AX=0$ if $\operatorname{rank}A\leq\frac{n}{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:
Given matrix $A\in M_n\left(K\right)$, $\operatorname{rank}(A)\leq\frac{n}{2}$. Prove that there exists $X\in M_n\left(K\right)$ such that $X$ is symmetrical and $X$ satisfies $AX=0$.

My thoughts.
I know that $\operatorname{rank}(X)\geq\frac{n}{2}$ as $\operatorname{rank}(X)=n-\operatorname{rank}$. And than I stuck.

EDIT

$X$ is non-zero

Symmetrical means $X=X^T$

Comment: What is symmetric significant? Wouldn't $XX^T$ be a solution if $X$ is?

Comment: If your question is just the first paragraph, then take $X$ to be the zero matrix - a symmetric matrix - and existence is proved, but the condition on the rank of $A$  would not be necessary, so I think there is additional conditions to your question.

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri I've edit my question.

Comment: @jobe edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple if $K=\mathbb{R}$. Since $\operatorname{rank}(A) < n$. There is a $v \neq 0$ such that $Av=0$. Clearly $X=vv^T \neq 0$ (since $\operatorname{trace}(X) = \|v\|^2 > 0$) and is symmetric, and $AX=0$.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much!

Comment: Then $rank(A)\leq\frac{n}{2}$ is useless condition? We just need $rank(A)\lt n$

Answer (score 0):

Let,
$$
 A = USU^{-1}
$$

denote the eigen-decomposition of the matrix $A$. Since the rank of $A$ is less than $\frac{n}{2}$ it follows that there are at least $\frac{n}{2}$ zero eigen-values.

If we let,
$$
  \hat{U} = [\textbf{u}_0, \ldots,\textbf{u}_k, \ldots  \textbf{u}_K]
$$
denote the eigen vectors corresopnding to the zero eigen-values, i.e,
$$
  A \textbf{u}_k = 0
$$
then,
$$
  A \hat{U} = 0
$$
It follows that,
$$
 A \hat{U}\hat{U}^T = 0
$$
and so we can let $X = \hat{U}\hat{U}^T$.